# Micronaut returns a Unexpected error occurred: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Tags: java, jpa, micronaut

I'm trying to run a simple Micronaut 2.0 application.
I've included the `@Transional` annotation in my service.
When I execute it, it returns the following error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at io.micronaut.transaction.hibernate5.MicronautSessionContext.currentSession(MicronautSessionContext.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:475)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.hibernate.jpa.TransactionalSessionInterceptor.intercept(TransactionalSessionInterceptor.java:56)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:69)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.hibernate.jpa.TransactionalSession$Intercepted.persist(Unknown Source)
    at sh.platform.micronaut.HeroService.save(HeroService.java:29)
    at sh.platform.micronaut.HeroController.save(HeroController.java:36)
    at sh.platform.micronaut.$HeroControllerDefinition$Intercepted.$$access0(Unknown Source)
    at sh.platform.micronaut.$HeroControllerDefinition$Intercepted$$proxy0.invokeInternal(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractExecutableMethod.invoke(AbstractExecutableMethod.java:146)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:60)
    at io.micronaut.validation.ValidatingInterceptor.intercept(ValidatingInterceptor.java:106)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:69)
    at sh.platform.micronaut.$HeroControllerDefinition$Intercepted.save(Unknown Source)
    at sh.platform.micronaut.$$HeroControllerDefinition$InterceptedDefinition$$exec1.invokeInternal(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractExecutableMethod.invoke(AbstractExecutableMethod.java:146)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext$4.invoke(DefaultBeanContext.java:468)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.AbstractRouteMatch.execute(AbstractRouteMatch.java:313)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.RouteMatch.execute(RouteMatch.java:117)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.lambda$buildResultEmitter$11(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1304)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableDefer.subscribeActual(FlowableDefer.java:35)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.context.ServerRequestContextFilter$1.subscribe(ServerRequestContextFilter.java:65)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromPublisher.subscribeActual(FlowableFromPublisher.java:29)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:82)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker$BooleanRunnable.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:288)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:253)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I tried to follow this [tutorial](https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-data-access-jpa-hibernate/guide/index.html),but without sucess.

I've created this simple repository with my code: https://github.com/soujava/micronaut-jpa

Steps:

Execute a PostgreSQL instance:

```sh
docker run --ulimit memlock=-1:-1 -it --rm=true --memory-swappiness=0 --name micronaut_test -e POSTGRES_USER=micronaut -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=micronaut -e POSTGRES_DB=micronaut -p 5432:5432 postgres:10.5
```

Execute the Java application and Post an entity:

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/heroes' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"name": "Iron man"}'
```

Comment: Problem solved, the solution is on the git repository: https://github.com/soujava/micronaut-jpa

Comment: I am also facing the same issue with the Micronaut using Hibernate/Jpa. How did you able to solve that? Could you please explain the problem and the solution you had?

Comment: Hey, I solved using this commit: https://github.com/soujava/micronaut-jpa/commit/b9dcd0f88d14ccb5e25d5c71d61a9162a6645804

Comment: Did you end up reporting the problem with this tutorial to the Micronaut authors? I ran into this today. Your GitHub example is helpful, but I don't fully understand it because I'm using Gradle, not Maven. It looks like there are annotation processor dependencies missing, and maybe some sort of configuration for it (compiler arg?) but I'm not sure how to fix my Gradle configuration to get the tutorial working. The whole reason I followed a tutorial was because I'm new to a lot of this stuff, and wanted to walked through it. Maybe it would be a good idea to report this so it's fixed for others.

Comment: I opened an issue for it (https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/5733). I also tinkered a bit more once I realized the tutorial included a complete example. When I noticed that the Gradle dependencies didn't match between what I had at the end of the tutorial and the complete example, I changed my dependencies one at a time to match the complete example until I had it working.